# How to delete unnecessary dex files?

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex, appodeal

When I'm running my application with Appodeal and Multidex, I get next toast message:

```
Integration Error: <Library name> classes are already loaded from jar files, remove unnecessary dex files.
```

This error occurs after Appodeal initialization:

```
Appodeal.initialize(this, APPODEAL_API_KEY, Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL | Appodeal.BANNER | Appodeal.NATIVE | Appodeal.MREC);
```

Libraries, that cause an error,are included only as jars and not mentioned in **build.gradle**

How to delete unnecessary dex files?
And is it possible to manage library packaging in dex files?

Comment: Already been answered more in the appodeal there are two implementations with multidex activated and without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening .jar file (appodeal.jar) and remove dex.